# How to measure specific risk charge?

Tags: value-at-risk, banks, basel, market-risk

IFRS requires banks to compute different risks including market risk based on Basel iii.

To do so, the capital requirement is defined as follows:

$$max(VaR_{t−1},m_c × VaR_{avg}) + SRC$$

$SRC$ is a specific risk charge. How to calculate specific risk charge?

Comment: Specific Risk Charge, as far as I am concerned, is a non quantifiable risk, and might vary across different banks (idiosyncratic).  It might not be present due to strict financial criteria